# Develop Windows applications with Linux tools

Tags: linux, debugging, vim, mono

I like the Linux operating system and `vim` editor, but there are many companies that develop under Windows environment in `Visual studio` etc. There is a possibility that I will have to work for such a company in about a month.

I'd like to do my work on my Linux system and copy the files to them. I have experience with both developments and I found out that I don't want to work with MS products but I like programming and writing MS code is not such a pain.

Are you a similar developer? Could you give me some advice about your methodology to be most of the time on Linux platform, to create code and debug everything in vim on Linux and only when neccessary open Visual Studio with Windows forms and similar things and test the things that weren't possible to test in Linux environment?

I would see the work in creating small peaces of code on Linux, testing them and then move it to MS platform and integrate to the whole system. How do you debug and test your code? The development will be probably in `C#` or `C++`. I can't imagine `Visual Basic`.

Please write here your experience, style of work, if this has sence or there are too many troubles and I should rather give up.

So the question is: How to develop applications that run on Windows with Linux tools, without touching Visual Studio and browsing with Windows file manager etc.

thank you

Comment: I would advise you to open your mind (and eyes) and use Visual Studio. Or find a non-MS platform job if you are so much against it, that you are willing to go over so many hoops just to avoid typing code inside VS.

Comment: Visual Studio is a fantastic tool. Put your platform zealotry aside and try using it.

Comment: @DBM I hope this won't be discussion about the fantastic Visual Studio. For me it's too slow and I wasn't satisfied with it in the past.

Comment: My experience is that although VS is highly customizable, the command set of vi cannot be achieved there (without special plugins). Working still in vi or vi-like environment is okay if you don't stay with C# for a long time, but if this is going to be your main job, I would recommend to do what I did: just get used to the inconveniences of Visual Studio and learn about its conveniences and advantages. Visual Studio is not so bad, after all, but it takes time to switch the mindset after living in vi universe.

Comment: @Vlad I began in Visual Studio world. I was developing in it for 8 months and knew VS quite well (used extensions and was playing with extensibility VSX) but after I hit the lightweight Linux tools especially vim everything was better.

Comment: I'm what you might term "A Linux Die Hard", But I do admit that VS is quite a good IDE.  The best advice I can give is use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I'd install MinGW or Cygwin on your windows machine and just use gvim/vim anyway (or maybe just use the Win32 vim).

VS is just a big editor. You'll be building with the microsoft compilers ( perhaps using msbuild or nmake ) but probably are going to have to accept that you can only debug windows things with VS ( unless you build *for* MinGW or Cygwin and use gcc and gdb)

Comment: It would be great if there would be ncurses debugger. VS debugger is quite good but I don't like the long waiting when VS closes and opens (now are computers faster but I believe that VS will be still slow).

Comment: @xralf for .Net there is mdbg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Not sure, if this will help you or not but there is a Vim Emulation layer for Visual Studio 2010 called VsVim.

Check out : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329

Comment: I'm afraid that this won't cover all things I already use with `vim`.

Comment: Interestingly this extension is created and managed by one of SO's high ranking user called JaredPar. You can follow his blog for more details on VsVim.Profile : http://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vim` as a code editor, you can even stick on Linux when developing software for the .NET platform. The people behind the [Mono](http://mono-project.com) make this happen. Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily create cross platform applications. It is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .Net Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime.

You can stick to the editor of your liking and use the tools that come with Mono to compile your stuff. There is a IDE called [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/), but compared to Visual Studio it is pretty basic... and compared to VIM it lacks simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

C# projects are plain text files so it's easy enough to edit them over an SMB share in whatever editor you wish from anywhere the sysadmins let you.
Testing however will be difficult without going back to the windows machine, and while Mono implements the framework, it's still a different environment if you're targeting Windows.

Comment: I hoped that something could simulate Windows environment most of the time and debug most of the errors on Linux and only once a day test the application under Windows.

Comment: The best way if simulating a Windows environment is to use Windows... Ignoring the Mono/.Net difference, Linux itself works very different to Windows. You're just trying to make things difficult for yourself :)

Comment: @Vlad I'm thinking rather about Cygwin, but it seems that nobody here has real experience with using the effective tools and at the same time go with commercial needs.

Comment: @xralf, I use cygwin daily, our (older) windows build servers are all wired together using tcl, perl and cygwin.  You can't write software for windows on linux that easily unless you are prepared to write proper portable code. With C# this is easy but your co-workers might not thank you as mono doesn't support everything.  For C++ you will find that boost works pretty well as a cross platform toolset but you are still going to need to debug on windows using the MS tools.